# How to optimize queries in Django Rest Framework serializers (DRF)?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, django-rest-framework

**info**: I have component model with search_tags field which is a many to many field with Search model
and i have a serializer for Component model which is ComponentSerializer and i using get_videos
method to get videos for each component and i want to get videos for each search tag in
search_tags field and store them into a `filtered_data_list` and return it as a response

The response time is very slow and i want to optimize it and i don't know how to do it (I am new to django and rest framework)

[image]

```py
class ComponentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ''' component serializer '''

    videos = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Component
        fields = ['title', 'slug', 'videos']

    def get_videos(self, obj):
        filtered_data_list = []

        for search in obj.search_tags.select_related('component').filter(is_active=True):
            ''' Thumbnails if thumbnail is not None '''
            thumbnail = search.thumbnail.url if search.thumbnail else None
            ''' Query for videos '''
            videos = YTVideo.objects.select_related('channel').filter(
                Q(channel=search.channel) | Q(channel__category__name=search.category),
                reduce(operator.or_, (Q(title__icontains=tag) for tag in search.content.split(',')))
            ).order_by(search.ordering_field)[:search.limit]

            ''' Append data to filtered_data_list excluding multile arrays '''
            for video in videos.select_related('channel'):
                if thumbnail:
                    video.thumbnail = thumbnail
                filtered_data_list.append(video)

        return YTVideoSerializer(filtered_data_list, many=True).data
```

Comment: You need to read up on those things and try them, then ask questions where you get stuck.  As it is, this looks like a help wanted ad, not a request for help.

Comment: Share your model's?